# How to append text to input value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok, so I am trying to create a calculator. This is a trivial problem but I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I looked everywhere online for other solutions but everybody recommends the way I have done. However, it doesn't work.

Here is the code: 
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans+SC:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <h1>Calculator Pro</h1>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="mainDiv">
            <div id="resultsDiv">
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                <input type="text" id="resultsInput" readonly>
            </div>
            <div id="firstRow">
                <div class="numpad">
                    <p class="numOps seven">7</p>
                </div>
                <div class="numpad">
                    <p class="numOps eight">8</p>
                </div>
                <div class="numpad">
                    <p class="numOps nine">9</p>
                </div>
                <div class="numpad operatorDiv">
                    <p class="numOps divide">/</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="firstRow">
                <div class="numpad">
                    <p class="numOps four">4</p>
                </div>
                <div class="numpad">
                    <p class="numOps five">5</p>
                </div>
                <div class="numpad">
                    <p class="numOps six">6</p>
                </div>
                <div class="numpad operatorDiv">
                    <p class="numOps multiply">*</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="firstRow">
                <div class="numpad">
                    <p class="numOps one">1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="numpad">
                    <p class="numOps two">2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="numpad">
                    <p class="numOps three">3</p>
                </div>
                <div class="numpad operatorDiv">
                    <p class="numOps substract">-</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="firstRow">
                <div class="numpad">
                    <p class="numOps zero">0</p>
                </div>
                <div class="numpad">
                    <p class="numOps decimal">.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="numpad" id="equalSignDiv">
                    <p id="equalSign">=</p>
                </div>
                <div class="numpad operatorDiv">
                    <p class="numOps add">+</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="myscripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html
```

jQuery:

```
var temp_string = "";

$("#resultsInput").val("0");
//clears the results Div
$(".fa-times").click(function() {
  $("#resultsInput").val("0");
});


$(".numOps").click(function() {
  if ($("#resultsInput").val("0")) {
    $("#resultsInput").val($(this).text());
  } else {
    temp_string += $(this).text();
    $("#resultsInput").val($("#resultsInput").val() + $(this).text());
  }
});
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: What is expected result of `if ($("#resultsInput").val("0"))` ? Missing closing `>` at `</html`

Comment: `if ($("#resultsInput").val("0"))` You are setting value, not getting it. It is always truthly...

Comment: @A.Wolff Wow, silly me! Thank you so much. I appreciate these quick answers. 
Solution: 
Switched ($("#resultsInput").val("0")) with ($("#resultsInput").val() === "0") and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `this` in the wrong way.

```
$("#resultsInput").val($("#resultsInput").val() + $(this).text());
                                                      ^-- This points to input field and not .numOps
```

So do

```
$("#resultsInput").val($("#resultsInput").val() + temp_string);
```

Or

```
$("#resultsInput").val(function(){$(this).val() + temp_string});
```

Comment: Surely because this is wrong statment: `This points to input field and not .numOps`

Comment: yeah, $(this) points to the element where the function is being called on. Thank you anyways. Appreciate the effort!

Answer (score 0):

Missing closing `</div>` , closing `>` at `</html` ; substituted `if ($("#resultsInput").val() === "0")` for `if ($("#resultsInput").val("0"))` ; substituted `$("#resultsInput").val(Number($("#resultsInput").val()) + Number($(this).text()));` for `$("#resultsInput").val($("#resultsInput").val() + $(this).text());`

```js
var temp_string = "";

$("#resultsInput").val("0");
//clears the results Div
$(".fa-times").click(function() {
  $("#resultsInput").val("0");
});

$(".numOps").click(function() {
  if ($("#resultsInput").val() === "0") {
    $("#resultsInput").val($(this).text());
  } else {
    temp_string += $(this).text();
    $("#resultsInput").val(Number($("#resultsInput").val()) + Number($(this).text()));
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans+SC:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <h1>Calculator Pro</h1>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="mainDiv">
            <div id="resultsDiv">
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                <input type="text" id="resultsInput" readonly>
            </div>
            <div id="firstRow">
                <div class="numpad">
                    <p class="numOps seven">7</p>
                </div>
                <div class="numpad">
                    <p class="numOps eight">8</p>
                </div>
                <div class="numpad">
                    <p class="numOps nine">9</p>
                </div>
                <div class="numpad operatorDiv">
                    <p class="numOps divide">/</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="firstRow">
                <div class="numpad">
                    <p class="numOps four">4</p>
                </div>
                <div class="numpad">
                    <p class="numOps five">5</p>
                </div>
                <div class="numpad">
                    <p class="numOps six">6</p>
                </div>
                <div class="numpad operatorDiv">
                    <p class="numOps multiply">*</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="firstRow">
                <div class="numpad">
                    <p class="numOps one">1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="numpad">
                    <p class="numOps two">2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="numpad">
                    <p class="numOps three">3</p>
                </div>
                <div class="numpad operatorDiv">
                    <p class="numOps substract">-</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="firstRow">
                <div class="numpad">
                    <p class="numOps zero">0</p>
                </div>
                <div class="numpad">
                    <p class="numOps decimal">.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="numpad" id="equalSignDiv">
                    <p id="equalSign">=</p>
                </div>
                <div class="numpad operatorDiv">
                    <p class="numOps add">+</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
var temp_string = "";
var default_val = "0";

$("#resultsInput").val(default_val);

//clears the results Div

$(".fa-times").click(function() {
  $("#resultsInput").val(default_val);
});


$(".numOps").click(function() {

  temp_string += $this.text();

  $("#resultsInput").val(temp_string);

});
```